# What is the overhead of creating docker images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm exploring using docker so that we deploy new docker images instead of specific file changes, so all of the needs of the application come with each deployment etc.

**Question 1:**

If I add a new application file, say 10 MB, to a docker image when I deploy the new image, using the tools in Docker tool box, will this require the deployment of an entirely new image to my containers or do docker deployments just take the difference between the 2, similar to git version control?

Another way to put it, I looked on a list of docker base images and saw a version of ubuntu that is 188 MB. If I commit a new application to a docker image, using this base image, will my docker containers need to pull the full 188 MB, which they are already running, plus the application or is there a differential way of just getting what has changed?

**Supplementary Question**

Am I correct in assuming when using docker, deploying images is the intended approach? Meaning any new changes should require a new image deployment so that images are treated as immutable? When I was using AWS we followed this approach with AMI (Amazon Machine Images) but storing AMIs had low overhead, for docker I don't know yet.

Or is it a better practice to deploy dockerfiles and have the new image be built on the container itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker uses a layered union filesystem, only one copy of a layer will be pulled by a docker engine and stored on its filesystem. When you build an image, docker will check its layer cache to see if the same parent layer and same command have been used to build an existing layer, and if so, the cache is reused instead of building a new layer. Once any step in the build creates a new layer, all following steps will create new layers, so the order of your Dockerfile matters. You should add frequently changing steps to the end of the Dockerfile so the earlier steps can be cached.

Therefore, if you use a 200MB base image, have 50MB of additions, but only 10MB are new additions at the end of your Dockerfile, you'd push 250MB the first time to a docker engine, but only 10MB to an engine that already had a previous copy of that image, or 50MB to an engine that just had the 200MB base image.

The best practice with images is to build them once, push them to a registry (either self hosted using the registry image, cloud hosted by someone like AWS, or on Docker Hub), and then pull that image to each engine that needs to run it.

For more details on the layered filesystem, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Comment: Thanks. Reading over this...If I understand you correctly, the docker Pull, is what makes this efficient, by taking changed layers. As oppose to if I was to manually copy the image files to the container each time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "manually copy the image files to the container". A container is a running instance of an image. If you copy an image with `docker save` and `docker load` instead of using a registry server to push and pull the image, then you will end up sending all layers to the destination each time. That is not a recommended practice.

Comment: yes that what I meant by "manually copying". Taking the image files whole vs using the "docker pull" command. Thanks This answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also work a little, in order to  create smaller images.
You can use Alpine or Busybox instead of using bigger Ubuntu, Debian or Bitnami (Debian light).

A smaller image is more secure as less tools are available.

Some reading

http://blog.xebia.com/how-to-create-the-smallest-possible-docker-container-of-any-image/

https://www.dajobe.org/blog/2015/04/18/making-debian-docker-images-smaller/

You have 2 great tools in order to make smaller docker images

https://github.com/docker-slim/docker-slim

and

https://github.com/mvanholsteijn/strip-docker-image

Some examples with docker-slim

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/grafana-xxl.slim/

shows

`size before -> 357.3 MB`

and `using docker-slim -> 18.73 MB`

or about simh

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/simh_bitnami.slim/

`size 5.388 MB`

when the original

`k3ck3c/simh_bitnami 88.86 MB`

a popular netcat image

chilcano/netcat is 135.2 MB

when a netcat based on Alpine is 7.812 MB

and based on busybox will need 2 or 3 MB

Comment: Thanks for the docker-slim info. This is off topic but do you have any recommendations for how to get the  remote docker container to pull new changes? I've been looking at docker-machine but I also read that some simply set a cron job on the container to pull every minute so now direct connect to the remote container is necessary. The latter sounds intriguing.

Comment: you mean, a running container should check if a new image is available? I think this "job" should be devoted to some script, not to a container

Comment: Well in this case it would be a script or cron job running on the system that the container is on. The script would periodically attempt to pull the latest image stop the container, update it, then run it, assuming this only takes place when the image has changed.

Comment: You should use the Docker Hub API if you want to ask for the creation date of an image on the Docker Hub or your Hub, see https://docs.docker.com/v1.4/reference/api/docker-io_api/ see also this odc http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/docker/docker-tutorial-series-part-7-ultimate-guide-for-docker-apis